# Incorrect locale from dateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, date, locale, nsdateformatter

I have problem with my DateFormatter.

My iOS app communicates with server and uses `If-Modified-Since` header with date created with following formatter:

```
modifiedSinceDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
modifiedSinceDateFormatter!.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
modifiedSinceDateFormatter!.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
modifiedSinceDateFormatter!.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
```

It works as expected - returning date in following format: `Fri, 08 Sep 2017 07:02:20 GMT`.

But I was looking through the server logs and found that once request was made with following date format `sob., 26 sie 2017 10:17:01 CEST` (that's correct Polish locale and timezone - I expect my users to use Polish locale).

So my question is:
How is it possible that this formatter returned date in the wrong locale? Are there some options that user can activate to override this locale (like Accessibility options)? Can it be some jailbroken device?

EDIT: And it happened again: `wt., 17 kwi 2018 08:40:02 CEST`. Interesting that there was few requests (at same moment from single device) and only one of them failed - with wrong date).

Comment: Are you sure that your server (or logs) don't show/transform the UTC date into its own format localized to where the servers stands? That's sometimes useful for server developers that the UTC date its translated (some UI tool maybe) to not "remove/add hours mentally", if the serveurs is in Poland for instance.

Comment: @Larme No, that's not the case (if so, there should be more similar logs). App has been communicating with the server for some time and I didn't spot this problem. Also, it happened once. At the time of this event, there weren't any updates in iOS or server code.
Maybe it's coincidental with some updates by the cloud provider. It's possible that it's not a iOS app fault, but maybe someone observed something similar.

Comment: Looking at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) a possible solution for you could be to use a POSIX locale instead, so "en_US_POSIX" (I just realized this question is quite old)

Comment: Yes, question is old, but I still don't know how to fix described problem. I edited question today with new error (same situation). Thank you for suggestion, I'll look it up. But the most interesting part of question for me is "why this happened?" :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the following explanation on how to ensure you get your date properly parsed using English names for months and days

> Unless you specifically need month and/or weekday names to appear in the user's language, you should always use the special locale of en_US_POSIX. This will ensure your fixed format is actually fully honored and no user settings override your format. This also ensures month and weekday names appear in English. Without using this special locale, you may get 24-hour format even if you specify 12-hour (or visa-versa). And dates sent to a server almost always need to be in English.

I found the quote [on this page](http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html)